# how to solve sending email every time the page is refreshed

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

These form work after submission .but after refreshing the page the mail send again and again.

```
<?php
$to = "abc.com";
$subject = "This is subject";
$message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
$message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
$header = "From:mithlesh@rightturn.co.in \r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if( $retval == true ) {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
}else {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

Comment: What dont you put this within if(isset($_POST))?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, sorry my friend. It was showing some error, net problems. Multiple comment was never my intensn

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `submit`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
}
```

So your code is :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "abc.com";
    $subject = "This is subject";
    $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
    $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
    $header = "From:mithlesh@rightturn.co.in \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if( $retval == true ) {
       echo "Message sent successfully...";
    }else {
       echo "Message could not be sent...";
    }
}
```

Comment: if user reload's the page POST data is still have `$_POST['submit']` So Above Code is executed whenever the user reloads

Comment: Then you have to use Ajax

Comment: sir when i run this code is not working

Comment: Can you please show me your Form ?

Comment: or clear the `$_POST = array()` after send

Comment: no i dont want any form

Answer (score -1):

Mostly mail sending happens after particular event or activity just like form-submit or button-click.. you need to design form with relevant fields.. then you can use isset() or !empty() for $_POST array

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $to = "abc.com";
     $subject = "This is subject";
      $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
     $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
     $header = "From:mithlesh@rightturn.co.in \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
}
```

Comment: After refreshing Page still have post data

Comment: In your code, you have not used form handling or post-array.. you have to check it first in any php tutorial

Answer (score -1):

put this code in starting of your php code outside isset submit button

```
if(empty($_SESSION['key']) && !isset($_SESSION['key'])){
  $randomkey = rand(0,99999);
  $mykey = $_SESSION['key'] = $randomkey
}
```

It set Session a unique random key. now in form field take one hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?=$mykey?>">
```

Now On Submit

First Check Current `$mykey` Matches With Hidden Variable
After Performing Certain Action Unset `$mykey`
So it prevent user adding data multiple times by Refreshing the page.

I hope it Helps... :-)

Comment: no i want form feild

Comment: i did not want a form feild

Comment: you can mark this as answer